# How to implement pusher client using asyncio with python

Tags: python, package, client, python-asyncio, pusher

I am currently using the [pysher](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/Pysher) python package as basis for my pusher client with python 3.5.
Based on my experiences pysher is currently not capable to recover from pusher errors or temporary interruptions of the internet connection, resulting in loss of pusher notifications. Also the performance requirement (CPU usage and memory) is too high, resulting in the need to kill and restart the pusher clients every now and then.

I would therefore like to implement a python 3.5 based pusher client in an alternative way (without the pysher package). As I have heard asyncio would be very suitable for this use case, I would like to consider this too.

How can I implement this?

Thanks!